# Get all image URLs from Amazon API

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, api

You can use this code to get the first image URL of one specific item on amazon:

```
from amazon.api import AmazonAPI

amazon = AmazonAPI(aws_key='XXX', aws_secret='XXX', aws_associate_tag='XXX', region="DE")
product = amazon.lookup(ItemId='B003P0ZB1K')
print(product.large_image_url)
```

but how can you get to all image URLs of that item, instead of only getting the first one? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the 'Images' response group in your request.

`product = amazon.lookup(ItemId='B003P0ZB1K', ResponseGroup='Images')`

The list of XML ImageSets can then be accessed via the images property, but will need to be parsed using an XML parser.

`product.images`

Please check out this article for information on parsing XML in python:
[How do I parse XML in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python)

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/RG_Images.html

From the source code of the library:

```
@property
def images(self):
    """List of images for a response.
    When using lookup with RespnoseGroup 'Images', you'll get a
    list of images. Parse them so they are returned in an easily
    used list format.
    :return:
        A list of `ObjectifiedElement` images
    """
    try:
        images = [image for image in self._safe_get_element(
            'ImageSets.ImageSet')]
    except TypeError:  # No images in this ResponseGroup
        images = []
    return images
```

The image set XML looks like this:

```
<ImageSets>
  <ImageSet Category="primary">
  <SwatchImage>
  <URL>https://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51YL4rlI%2B9L._SL30_.jpg</URL>
  <Height Units="pixels">30</Height>
  <Width Units="pixels">23</Width>
  </SwatchImage>
  <SmallImage>
  <URL>https://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51YL4rlI%2B9L._SL75_.jpg</URL>
  <Height Units="pixels">75</Height>
  <Width Units="pixels">58</Width>
  </SmallImage>
  <ThumbnailImage>
  <URL>https://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51YL4rlI%2B9L._SL75_.jpg</URL>
  <Height Units="pixels">75</Height>
  <Width Units="pixels">58</Width>
  </ThumbnailImage>
  <TinyImage>
  <URL>https://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51YL4rlI%2B9L._SL110_.jpg</URL>
  <Height Units="pixels">110</Height>
  <Width Units="pixels">86</Width>
  </TinyImage>
  <MediumImage>
  <URL>https://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51YL4rlI%2B9L._SL160_.jpg</URL>
  <Height Units="pixels">160</Height>
  <Width Units="pixels">124</Width>
  </MediumImage>
  <LargeImage>
  <URL>https://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51YL4rlI%2B9L.jpg</URL>
  <Height Units="pixels">500</Height>
  <Width Units="pixels">389</Width>
  </LargeImage>
 </ImageSet>
</ImageSets>
```

Comment: Thanks, tried that too but there is still a problem.
Instead of getting image URLs I get some kind of reference?!

`[<Element {http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2013-08-01}ImageSet at 0x1eb21798c48>, <Element {http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2013-08-01}ImageSet at 0x1eb21776d88>]`

Comment: Looking at the source, there is a property @images which will return a list of all image URLs, you should be able access that with: `product.images`

Comment: I guess i'm missing something...
Thats my code:
`product = amazon.lookup(ItemId='B003P0ZB1K', ResponseGroup='Images')
print(product.images)`.
And it prints me that exact reference text I posted in my last comment... thanks.

Comment: What version of the amazon.api are you using?  Also, the response is a list of Element objects which means the XML response from the Amazon API is not being parsed.

Comment: Python 3.5.2: python-amazon-simple-product-api 2.2.11

Comment: Are you still having issues parsing the XML?